# best way to get iso into usa format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

trying to convert my date string into usa format

'20150316 16:28'
into
'3/16/2015 4:28 pm'

(Note: 24hr format is fine too)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/862

Comment: Why do you want a regional, ambiguous format? So that when you output 7/9/2015 your users will have to call support to see if that means July 9 or September 7?

Comment: are you saying to use utc format

Comment: No, I'm saying to use ISO format, like yyyy-mm-dd. Or let the client determine the regional settings to use. Or perform the formatting in the client, which has much more powerful string formatting than T-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predefined format "g" will give you a date time in this format:

```
select FORMAT(cast('20150316 16:20' as datetime), 'g')
```

Update:

```
select format( cast('20150316 16:20' as datetime), 'd') 
+ ' ' + format( cast('20150316 16:20' as datetime), 'HH:mm')
```

Produces `3/16/2015 16:20`

See these articles for predefined and custom date time formats:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Note these will vary by culture.

Comment: what would it be for 24hr

Comment: @Rod From your question "'3/16/2015 4:28 pm'" is not 24 hour time.  'g' matches the example in your question.

Answer (score -1):

select convert(varchar(15),cast('20150316 16:28'  as datetime),101)+' '+convert(varchar(5),cast('20150316 16:28'  as datetime),114)